# what's the difference between Config.getString() and configurationService.getConfiguration().getString()

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

Either way we get the string property we wanted from `.property` files. So what's the difference between `Config.getString()` and `configurationService.getConfiguration().getString()` in hybris platform?

And as another question;

if we `getString()` a property which exists in both `project.properties` and `local.properies` with different values, which one do we get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't compared the difference between the two, but `ConfigurationService` is preferred, as a best practice.

From [Example of a Code Review Checklist](https://www.sap.com/cxworks/article/461035610/example_of_a_code_review_checklist):

```
Configuration - Use the ConfigurationService interface rather than the de.hybris.platform.util.Config object.
```